# Manager Field on User object

Tags: security

Does the Manager Field on the User object control Security Access ?
For Ex. if I setup User 1 as manager of User 2 then, would User 2 start seeing records owned by User 1 that they could not previously ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your other security settings like "Organisation Wide Defaults" for that object as well as the "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" setting. [Here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_managers_only.htm&language=en_US) you can find a good explanation around how that works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, from the link it seems that user can see records if the "Grant Access using hierarchy" is disabled and a sharing rule is created to open access. However it doesnt say what happens when Grant access is enabled and there is no sharing Rule, would the manager still see the owners record ? (especially in the scenario where we are not using role hierarchy).

Comment: In that case I don't think the manager will be able to see the records. I would give it a try to be 100% sure :)